# Parsing Data for android-21 failed Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 in mac os Eclipse

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, android-sdk-tools, java-6

> i am using Mac os x Yosemite version 10.10.1 And Eclipse Luna 4.4
>
> i integrated Android SDK into Eclipse and it showing the Following Error

[image: when i open the project its says like this]

> i searched in net and i came to know that this problem is based on java JDK version problem.
>
> in My mac i installed JDK 1.6 and 1.7 and 1.8 as well.
>
> i know JDK 1.6 will not support for android 5. so in Eclipse i set the java compiler to JDK 1.7 but after setting if i restart the Eclipse its again setting to JDK 1.6 .
>
> My question is which JDK will support the Android SDK in Mac. And How to completely uninstall the JDK 1.6 from my mac machine.
>
> i am facing this problem for last two days but i can not get the solution yet. can anyone kindly help to overcome this problem.
>
> My simple need is i wants to run the Android in mac machine .

Comment: What do you mean, "i know JDK 1.6 will not support for android 5"?

Comment: @nitind i have installed JDk 1.6 in windows machine its not  supported in android 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is solved . after searching lots of this i got the solution.
>
> The answer is
>
> Eclipse should be 64 bit version,
>   and to use android the java JDK should be 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Bro, take a look at this post:

http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/15/how-to-switch-jdk-version-on-mac-os-x-maverick/

Answer (score 1):

Update to Eclipse Luna 64 bit with at least JDK 1.7 and I nearly guarantee everything will work.