# Parsing Data for android-21 failed on JDK1.8

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Been facing this issue on the out of the box standard android 21 application see attached
[image: Issue with Android L]

I am on 10.9.5 Mac OS X
I am currently on JDK 1.8 see

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In eclipse it shows the following:
[image]

I have tried switching the JDK versions and also installing/uninstalling eclipse, SDK and SDK tools.

Everything works fine in Android studio but not eclipse. unfortunately I have to get it to work on Eclipse.

Would appreciate any pointers you may have on the issue!

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886468/parsing-data-for-android-l-failed-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436999/parsing-data-for-android-21-failed-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643058/parsing-data-for-android-21-failed-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-in-mac-o). And check your Java compliance level.

Comment: Already looked at these @Tom nothing solved the problem

Comment: And what is your current compliance level?

Comment: I have tried both, 1.7 and 1.6

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install JDK version 1.7. Android doesn't support JDK v1.8 yet. You can get the latest JDK v1.7 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Also, when you update your Android SDK, you **must** also update your Android Development Tools (ADT) for Eclipse at the same time. If you don't, you'll get all sorts of errors.

**UPDATE:** As of April 27 2015, Mac® OS X® version 10.9.5 and JDK version 1.8 are not yet supported by Android SDK. See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for more info.